# How to point docker to run a React app and open in browser?

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run a docker on my React app but it does not connect. Actually I see it is up at address 0.0.0.0:3000, but does not open in a browser. I am new to docker and still figuring out in how it works. How can I connect and open the app?

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  node:
    build: .
    image: node:16
    container_name: myapp
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    command: bash
    restart: always
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:16-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**Running at port 3000**

```
e810d9f622c0   node:16        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 minutes ago   Up 5 minutes               0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, :::3000->3000/tcp
```

Comment: You override the command in your compose file -  `command: bash`, why?

Comment: I guess it is needed to enter in container, doesn't it? Should I remove?

Comment: The `command` in compose or `CMD` in the Dockerfile is what is run when the container is started, in your case the CMD defined in the Dockerfile is correct and doesn't nneed to be overridden. Not sure what "it is needed to enter in container" means, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Your docker-compose file contains a number of misunderstandings

When you have both `build:` and `image:` docker-compose will build an image based on your dockerfile and tag it with the name you give in `image:`. However, you name yours `node:16` which is not a good idea since that could be mistaken for the official node image.

you have both `tty:` and `stdin_open:` set to true. If you want to run node, then there's no need to run it interactively.

Your `command:` overrides the CMD defined in the Dockerfile, so your `npm start` command is no longer run.

Setting `work_dir:` to `/app` is superfluous since the WORKDIR is already set to `/app` in the Dockerfile.

Mapping a volume to `/app` hides everything in the `/app` path in the docker image. You've probably added this to get hot reload. Doing it this way is not a good idea, since it makes evereything in your Dockerfile that builds the `/app` directory irrelevant.

That leaves us with

```
version: "3"

services:
  node:
    build: .
    container_name: myapp
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

Run that and you should be able to go to `http://localhost:3000/` and see your app.

Comment: `container_name:` is also unnecessary: Compose picks its own name in a reasonably predictable way, and in most cases there are `docker-compose` equivalents to plain `docker` commands you might want to use to manipulate a container.